# How can I create inline comments (without using backslash to continue on another line)?

Tags: python

Sorry in advance if this is something really easy, I'm very new to Python. This seems like it should be something very simple, but I am having a frustratingly hard time finding an answer online.

I'm writing a Python script in a preliminary, pseudo sort of fashion at the moment, and don't have all variable defined yet. I want to be able to have comments in the middle of a line to symbolize where the variable will go, but without commenting out the entire rest of the line to the right.

To visualize what I mean, this is how what I want is done in C/C++:

```
int some_variable = /*some_variable_that_doesnt_exist_yet*/ + an_existing_variable;
```

Basically I need to be able to comment the middle of a line without commenting the left or right sides of said comment. Is there any way to do this?

I know there's a way to do it like this (or something similar to this):

```
some_variable = #some_variable_that_doesnt_exist_yet
                \+ an_existing_variable
```

...but I'd rather not do it that way if possible, just for ease of reading.

Comment: Since it'll be invalid syntax in general when it's commented out, since your operators won't have enough arguments, why not just use placeholder names for your variables? Like todo_undefined_variable. Then you can just do searches for todo_ to find vars you need to still define.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but you can *try* to use [triple quotes](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node70.html). Like `some_variable = """some_variable_that_doesnt_exist_yet""" + an_existing_variable`

Comment: Unary + is perfectly legal.

Comment: You're right, in general it won't be though :). Edited comment.

Comment: Won't work as it will try to append existing to the string.

Comment: Your problem is not how to put a placeholder, is why you haven't a clear idea of your variable yet, in the first place...

Comment: You can not... You can use `#` to make a single line comment, but you can not end comment part and keep writing your code within the same line. Or you can use multiple line comments

Comment: @thegrinner If you do that, you suddenly have a string in your expression (triple quotes are nothing but a string which supports newlines); that is usually not the effect one wants to achieve. For example if ``an_existing_variable`` is a numeric type, this will fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no. But you can always break things into multiple lines and comment in between. Parentheses come in handy for that.

```
my_var = (#some_variable +
         some_other_var)
```

Answer (score 2):

As with any language switch you will need to learn new habits that fit the features of the language. Python does not have the feature you desire, you could use some horrendous hack to force something that looks a bit similar in but I rather suggest you don't.

Some options are: document the TODO on a neighbouring line, perhaps using docstrings; don't sweat it and figure you'll add it later when your tests start requiring it; or use the fact that variables are lightweight and just create them with dummy values that leave the final calculation unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Inline comments do not exist in python.

The closest that I know of is the use of strings:

```
int some_variable = "some_variable_that_doesnt_exist_yet +" and an_existing_variable;
```

But that is terrible, and you should never do that.

Comment: I was afraid of that haha, I was worried that info was so sparse online it just couldn't be done. Thanks anyway for your help (and don't worry I won't do it that way, I promise)

Answer (score 0):

You can't: According to the documentation, comments in Python start with the hash character (*#*) and extend to the end of the physical line. See [An Informal Introduction to Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
name = "Use this for something later"
:
:
name = 27
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have inline or block comments like this. You can add a string (or any other expression), as suggested by others, but you will have to make sure to (consistently) replace all of those placeholders, which is extremely error prone

If it's only the value of the variable that is missing or unclear, and not the variable itself, how about this:

```
variable_to_be_defined = None # TODO define me!
some_other_variable = variable_to_be_defined + an_existing_variable
```

Comment: `None` + most things will raise an error. In py2.7 anyway. I haven't made much of a move to 3 yet. Does that change?

Comment: In this case, assign it something else, like a string `"define me"`. However, better have a runtime error than some illogical but silently accepted behaviour.